# Pandas, how to reorder by date

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe that has two columns and looks like:

```
    title      date
   Event0     2016-01-03
   Event1     2016-02-28
   Event2     2016-06-19
   Event3     2016-04-17
   Event4     2015-11-12
```

etc...

I would like to reorder the events by date in descending order by date and then create a python dictionary of the results.  Thus, I'd like my python dictionary's key(string),value(datetime) pair to look like:

```
result_dictionary = { 
    'Event2': 2016-06-19, 
    'Event3': 2016-04-17, 
    'Event1': 2016-02-28,  
    'Event0': 2016-01-03,  
    'Event4': 2015-11-12
}
```

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Thank-you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict), because you cannot sort a dict because `dictionary` has no ordering:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

d = df.set_index('title').date.to_dict()
print (d)
{'Event1': '2016-02-28', 
 'Event4': '2015-11-12', 
 'Event0': '2016-01-03', 
 'Event3': '2016-04-17', 
 'Event2': '2016-06-19'}


od = OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True))
print (od)
OrderedDict([('Event2', '2016-06-19'), 
             ('Event3', '2016-04-17'), 
             ('Event1', '2016-02-28'), 
             ('Event0', '2016-01-03'), 
             ('Event4', '2015-11-12')])
```

---

```
d = df.set_index('title').date.sort_values(ascending=False).to_dict()
print (d)
{'Event0': '2016-01-03', 
 'Event4': '2015-11-12', 
 'Event1': '2016-02-28',
 'Event3': '2016-04-17',
 'Event2': '2016-06-19'}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
dataframe.sort_values(by = 'date', ascending = False, inplace = True)
dataframe.to_dict()
```

docs here http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html

Comment: `to_dict` does not give directly what he wants. cf the answer of @jezrael